# jubatusのadvent calenderのサンプルについて

Tags: chainer

ubuntu16.04にて、jubatusをインストールしてshogunのサンプルを試そうとしてのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

jubatusサーバーにパスが通ってないような気がします。
具体的には、

```
$ jubaclassifier -f shogun.json
```

とうつと、

```
$ 2017-07-22 22:22:52,391 2367 FATAL [server_util.hpp:161] exception in main thread: jubatus::core::common::exception::runtime_error: Failed to get realpath
    (#0) API: realpath
    (#0) File: shogun.json
    (#0) Error: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません (2)
    (#0) Source: ../jubatus/server/common/filesystem.cpp
    (#0) Line: 67
    (#0) Function: std::__cxx11::string jubatus::server::common::real_path(const string&)


[1]+  中止                  (コアダンプ) jubaclassifier -f shogun.json
```

とでます、

一方、

```
jubaclassifier -f /opt/jubatus/share/jubatus/example/config/classifier/default.json &
```

とうつと、
サーバーが立ち上がります。

```
$ 2017-07-22 22:32:51,341 2466 INFO  [server_util.cpp:429] starting jubaclassifier 1.0.4 RPC server at 10.0.2.15:9199
    pid                  : 2466
    user                 : 
    mode                 : standalone mode
    timeout              : 10
    thread               : 2
    datadir              : /tmp
    logdir               : 
    log config           : 
    zookeeper            : 
    name                 : 
    interval sec         : 16
    interval count       : 512
    zookeeper timeout    : 10
    interconnect timeout : 10

2017-07-22 22:32:51,345 2466 INFO  [server_util.cpp:165] load config from local file: /opt/jubatus/share/jubatus/example/config/classifier/default.json
2017-07-22 22:32:51,435 2466 INFO  [classifier_serv.cpp:116] config loaded: {
  "converter" : {
    "string_filter_types" : {},
    "string_filter_rules" : [],
    "num_filter_types" : {},
    "num_filter_rules" : [],
    "string_types" : {
      "unigram": { "method": "ngram", "char_num": "1" },
      "bigram":  { "method": "ngram", "char_num": "2" },
      "trigram": { "method": "ngram", "char_num": "3" }
    },
    "string_rules" : [
      { "key" : "*", "type" : "bigram", "sample_weight" : "tf", "global_weight" : "idf" }
    ],
    "num_types" : {},
    "num_rules" : [
      { "key" : "*", "type" : "num" }
    ]
  },
  "parameter" : {
    "regularization_weight" : 1.0
  },
  "method" : "AROW"
}

2017-07-22 22:32:51,435 2466 INFO  [server_helper.hpp:226] start listening at port 9199
2017-07-22 22:32:51,435 2466 INFO  [server_helper.hpp:233] jubaclassifier RPC server startup
```

ちなみに、

`opt/jubatus/profile`

は、以下のようになっています。

```
export JUBATUS_HOME="/opt/jubatus"
export PATH="${JUBATUS_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JUBATUS_HOME}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
export LDFLAGS="-L${JUBATUS_HOME}/lib ${LDFLAGS}"
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="${JUBATUS_HOME}/include:${CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH}"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${JUBATUS_HOME}/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"
export MANPATH="${JUBATUS_HOME}/share/man:${MANPATH}"
```

どうすれば、advent calenderのサンプルを動かせますでしょうか？
アドバイスいただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージを見る限り、`shogun.json`が見つけられていないようで、相対パスが間違っているように見えます。

[こちら](http://qiita.com/TkrUdagawa/items/c07ef11fbc99ed18f49b)の記事をご覧になっているようでしたら、`jubatus_example`のshogunフォルダに移動した上で、`jubaclassifier`を起動してみてください。

```
$ git clone http://github.com/jubatus/jubatus-example.git
$ cd jubatus-example/shogun
$ jubaclassifier -f shogun.json
```